# Cassandra PDO connection PHP

Tags: php, pdo, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I've got Cassandra working nicely on Debian server however I'm hoping to connect to it from a PHP application.

Currently it seems PDO it the way to go for anything complex as I'm able to use CQL. I'm using the latest forked version of the Apache Cassandra-PDO project.

I'm using the latest Cassandra 2.03 and I can connect to it fine from CQLSH in the terminal.
When I try and connect in PHP using the following code

```
$db_handle = new PDO("cassandra:host=localhost;port=9160");
```

I get the following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'CQLSTATE[08006] [8]     TTransportException: Transport not open' in /var/www/index.php:9 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/index.php(9): PDO->__construct('cassandra:host=...') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/index.php on line 9
```

I've seem a few issues alike on the internet, but no solutions as yet. Hopefully someone can provide some insight into the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 8006 is connection failure. I think you need login and password in PDO Statment like this:
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=products', 'root', 'root');

Answer (score 0):

Try running 'nodetool status' from the cli to verify the IP address the server is running on.

Then perhaps change localhost to 127.0.0.1 if instead the local host.